# Crate new row depends on 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

After Year row need a new row as Year period if column 1 is year and column3< 2010 then columns values for year period is Below 2010 same as other rows

```
  Column1  Column2 ColumnX  Column3
0    Year        1       A     2009
1    Date        1       A       12
2    Year        2       A     2021
3    Year        3       A     2011
```

```
       Column1  Column2 ColumnX             Column3
0         Year        1       A                2009
1  Year period        1       A           Below2010
2         Date        1       A                  12
3         Year        2       A                2021
4  Year period        2       A           Above2020
5         Year        3       A                2011
6  Year period        3       A  Range in 2010/2020
```

Comment: So what ?
Explanations are quite unclear.
What have you tried so far ?
Post some code.

Comment: def get_period(row):
  if row["Column1"] == "Year":    
    row["Column1"] = "Year period"
    if row["Column3"] < 2010:
      row["Column3"] = "Below2010"
    elif row["Column3"] > 2020:
      row["Column3"] = "Above2020"
    else:
      row["Column3"] = "Range in 2010/2020"
 
    return row

s = df.apply(get_period, axis=1).dropna()

for i in s.index:
  upper = df.loc[:i, :]
  lower = df.loc[i+1:, :]
  df = pd.concat([upper, s.loc[i:i], lower], axis=0)
  
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter rows first in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for `Year` columns, replace `Column3` in [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and add substring to `Column1`, last join with original by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and sort indices by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
#necessary default RangeIndex
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df2 = df[df['Column1'].eq('Year')].copy()
df2['Column3'] = pd.to_numeric(df2['Column3'], errors='coerce')

df1 = (df2.assign(Column3 = lambda x: np.select([x['Column3']<2010, x['Column3']>2020], 
                                                  ['Below2010','Above2020'], 
                                                  default='Range in 2010/2020'),
                    Column1 =  lambda x: x['Column1'] + ' period'))

df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index(kind='mergesort', ignore_index=True)
print (df)
       Column1  Column2 ColumnX             Column3
0         Year        1       A                2009
1  Year period        1       A           Below2010
2         Date        1       A                  12
3         Year        2       A                2021
4  Year period        2       A           Above2020
5         Year        3       A                2011
6  Year period        3       A  Range in 2010/2020
```

Comment: Error : < not supported between instances of str and int

Comment: @Eswar - add `df['Column3'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Column3'], errors='coerce')`, answer was eited.

Comment: Please help me with some corrections,

Comment: What if have column3 values as Strings and empty values

Comment: @Eswar - If strings how possible compare years? Need numeric

Comment: @Eswar - Need `df['Column3'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Column3'], errors='coerce')` for numeric from strings and empty values

Comment: Somehows other Column3 values are gone missing

Comment: @Eswar - numeric data are converted wrong to  NaNs ?

Comment: Yeah some strings and some numerical values became empty cells

Comment: @Eswar - can you add some example of wrong converting numeric values?

Comment: Data not found, 128, 107.6, world-wide

Comment: @Eswar - I need data like list `print (df['Column3'].tolist())`

Comment: Except years , everything converted into Nan’s

Comment: @Eswar - I convert to numeric only filtered rows, answer was [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74557470/revisions)

Comment: Can you help me with @.      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74568501/convert-dataframe-into-json-file