# Create dataframe where column is a list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a list of tuples within a dataframe. Using code below :

```
# creating the Numpy array
array = np.array([[('A' , 1)], [('B' , 2)]])
  
# creating a list of index names
index_values = ['x1', 'x2']
   
# creating a list of column names
column_values = ['(a,b)']
  
# creating the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data = array, 
                  index = index_values, 
                  columns = column_values)
  
df
```

returns :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_45/2020978637.py in <module>
     13 df = pd.DataFrame(data = array, 
     14                   index = index_values,
---> 15                   columns = column_values)
     16 
     17 df

/opt/oss/conda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    676                     dtype=dtype,
    677                     copy=copy,
--> 678                     typ=manager,
    679                 )
    680 

/opt/oss/conda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in ndarray_to_mgr(values, index, columns, dtype, copy, typ)
    302         # by definition an array here
    303         # the dtypes will be coerced to a single dtype
--> 304         values = _prep_ndarray(values, copy=copy)
    305 
    306     if dtype is not None and not is_dtype_equal(values.dtype, dtype):

/opt/oss/conda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in _prep_ndarray(values, copy)
    553         values = values.reshape((values.shape[0], 1))
    554     elif values.ndim != 2:
--> 555         raise ValueError(f"Must pass 2-d input. shape={values.shape}")
    556 
    557     return values

ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(2, 1, 2)
```

Using a single element tuple :

```
array = np.array([[(1)], [(2)]])
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are creating the numpy array is wrong. Since it is an array of tuples, you will have to specify the `dtype` of the elements of the tuple while creating the array, and then later cast it back to an object type using `astype(object)`.

Do the following -

```py
array = np.array([[('A',1)], [('B',2)]], dtype=('<U10,int')).astype(object)

index_values = ['x1', 'x2']

column_values = ['(a,b)']

df = pd.DataFrame(data = array, index = index_values, columns = column_values)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     (a,b)
x1  (A, 1)
x2  (B, 2)
```